# sql multiple left joins with sum

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables as below. What I need to do is create a sumamry after left joining the 1st table to the 2nd and the 2nd to the 3rd.

[image: person]

[image: shopping_list]

[image: discount]

The code I'm using ends up resulting in a cartesian join. My query to create the 1st table (person) is complicated and resource intensive while the volume of data is table 2(shopping list) is massive so having a nested query is not ideal. Below is the code I'm using right now and the expected output (image 1) & what I get (image 2)

```sql
select
   a.ID,
   a.Name,
   sum(b.cost) total_cost,
   sum(c.discount_amount) total_discount
from
   person a,
   left join shopping_list b on a.id=b.id
   left join discount c on b.item = c.item
group by
   a.ID,
   a.Name
```

[image: correct]

[image: incorrect]

I've looked at the below links but I was hoping there's a solution that may work better give the size of my dataset

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217220/how-i-use-multiple-sum-with-multiple-left-joins

[Multiple Left Join with sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329525/multiple-left-join-with-sum)

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple rows for the discounts, so presummarize those:

```
select p.id, p.name, coalesce(sl.cost, 0) as cost,
       coalesce(d.discount_amount, 0) as discount_amount
from person p left join
     shopping_list sl
     on sl.id = p.id left join
     (select d.item, sum(discount_amount) as discount_amount
      from discount
      group by d.item
     ) d
     on sl.item = d.item
group by p.id, p.name;
```

The problem with your query is that the multiple rows of `discount` end up multiplying the rows of `shopping_list` -- resulting in the inaccurate totals.

Notice that in this query, the table aliases are abbreviations for the table names.  This is a best practice that makes it much, much easier to follow the logic of a query.