# Laravel join 3 tables and get the SUM

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 3 tables in my MariaDB 10.4.10 database which are `orders`, `commissions` and `order_items`.

Below is the table structure.

#### Orders

[image]

#### Commissions

[image]

### Order Items

[image]

I want to get `Totla commissions`, and `Total amount` using joins.

- Total amount is giving correct figure
- Total commssions is not

How I know this is by getting the data separately by using one join (which works correctly), but using 2 joins does not.

#### Getting total commissions only (Gives correct values)

```
$getstats = Order::select(
                DB::raw('SUM(sc.amount) as totalcommissions')
            )
            ->leftJoin('commissions as sc', 'sc.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->first();
```

#### Getting both total commissions and total amount (wrong values)

```
$getstats = Order::select(
                DB::raw('SUM(sc.amount) as totalcommissions'),
                DB::raw('SUM(oi.qty * oi.each) as totalamount')
            )
            ->leftJoin('order_items as oi', 'oi.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->leftJoin('commissions as sc', 'sc.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->first();
```

Does not give correct values.

### Example

The below give different values (see below for details).

First query:

```php
$getstatsorders = Order::select(
    DB::raw('SUM(oi.qty * oi.each) as totalamount'),
    DB::raw('SUM(sc.amount) as totalcommissions')
)
    ->leftJoin('commissions as sc', 'sc.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->leftJoin('order_items as oi', 'oi.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->first();
```

Results is

```
[
    "totalamount" => "41937.50"
    "totalcommissions" => "1649.56"
];
```

Second query

```php
$getstatsorders = Order::select(
    DB::raw('SUM(sc.amount) as totalcommissions')
)
     ->leftJoin('commissions as sc', 'sc.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
     ->first();
```

Results

```
[
    "totalcommissions" => "259.88"
]
```

- Why am I getting different results for `totalcommissions`? (1649.56 vs. 259.88)
- When I do the same for `totalamount` I am not getting different results.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please see my 2 examples `$getstats['totalcommissions']`, I am getting different values. Why is that happening

Comment: @hakre When I add this leftJoin `order_items as oi` then somehow `$getstats['totalcommissions']` is not not correct

Comment: You still have to describe what correct means. From my point of view, I only see code that works (it does something without crashing). Now you tell me the result it produces is not correct. As the code still looks correct to me (not you!), you need to give more context as otherwise I'm not able to see. Just consider I'm your grandma, and you need to explain it to me.  You can always [edit] your question, that works better than leaving comments only.

Comment: @hakre, Please see the edits. I have added some details

Comment: The smaller number is correct. I mean `$getstats['totalcommissions']`. Don't see the reason it should be different

Comment: MariaDB 10.4.10

Comment: What I can guess is that after you join another table then the results have duplicate entries thus the sum goes up. You should try grouping the results by the order_id @muya.dev

Answer (score 0):

> The smaller number is correct. [...] Don't see the reason it should be different

With each left join you will get +*n* result rows for each row on the left. *n* is zero or higher.

As in the first query you have two left joins, this will additionally add up.

Finally the SUM() is over all result rows.

That leaves you with sc.amount now being multiplied by the number of order items (second left join) per order.

This also explains why the lower value is correct for you (single left join, likely a 1:1 relationship) and the higher value too high (second left join, a 1:n relationship).

---

The problem you describe is basically the same as in *[How do I use multiple SUM with multiple LEFT JOINS()](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/217220/73034)* which shows an example for MySql (which should be compatible with Mariadb) using subqueries and there is a follow-up for SQL in general in *[sql multiple left joins with sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64893264/367456)*.

In MariaDB you can use SUM() as well as a window function, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sum/ , also for other examples and a description.